# kotlin and declaring variables correctly

Tags: android, kotlin

I have recently moved from java to kotlin. I am having some trouble managing variables. For example in Java I can easily declare a variable at the start of the class as

```
private Window window
```

Then when setting up the view I can initialise the window variable by using

```
window = activity.getWindow();

// clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

// add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

// finally change the color
window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.my_statusbar_color));
```

And finally if I want or need to I can change this status bar colour again at any point in the class simply by calling

```
window.setStatusBarColor
```

In Kotlin this same approach does not work. No matter what way I declare the variable at the top ie.

```
private var window: Window? = activity?.window
private lateinit var window: Window
private war window: Window? = null
```

Regardless of how I declare it when I try and set the status bar color in a method later down the class the window is always null.

Could someone please offer some explanation as to why this is occuring and how to implement the similar functionality that I had in Java.

Comment: Works fine for me. I'm in a Fragment and I'm calling the various methods on `window` from the `onActivityCreated()` callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Java code, you have two lines of relevance: the declaration of the field (`private Window window;`) and the assignment of a value to that field (`window = activity.getWindow();`).

In your Kotlin code variants:

- The first (`private var window: Window? = activity?.window`) has the declaration and the assignment in the same statement. This is fine, if `activity` is not `null` and `activity?.window` is not `null`. In your case, apparently it is, perhaps due to some Android timing issues.
- The second (`private lateinit var window: Window`) has no assignment, and there is no evidence that you assign it a value later.
- The third, after a typo correction (`private var window: Window? = null`) has an assignment, but the value is `null`. There is no evidence that you assign it a non-`null` value later.

I recommend that you use the third approach, but then put the same assignment in the same spot in the Kotlin code as you have it in the Java code:

```kotlin
window = activity?.window
```

Presumably, your Java code has it in the proper spot timing-wise.

Comment: Why do you recommend the third approach over a `lateinit var`?

Comment: @GavinWright: I don't know enough of the context of where this code is being used, and `getWindow()` can legit return `null`. So, I am not comfortable, in this circumstance, recommending `lateinit var`. `lateinit var` is fine in cases where you are really really sure that you will initialize it to a non-`null` value before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [CommonWare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63648530/12313157)

You can use either one of these approaches you mentioned

```
private lateinit var window: Window
private var window: Window? = null
```

Then in `onActivityCreated(Bundle?)` you can assign the value like so (In onActvityCreated the activity is never null):

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    window = requireActivity().window
}
```

Another approach, you lazily assign the value like so:

```
private val window: Window by lazy {
    requireActivity().window
}
```

Note: Either way ensure that you are using `window` variable on/after `onActivityCreated(Bundle?)`